# php how to calculate numbers sum after the loop

Tags: php

I have following loop to calculate comments and likes

```
function AddCampaignDetails($next=null){

    $AccessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN;
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/canonfanatic/media/recent?access_token=".$AccessToken;

    if($url !== null) {
        $url .= '&max_tag_id=' . $next;
    }

    /*//Also Perhaps you should cache the results as the instagram API is slow
    $cache = './'.sha1($url).'.json';
    if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){
        // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    }else{
        $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
    }*/

    $Ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $Result = curl_exec($Ch);
    curl_close($Ch);
    $Result = json_decode($Result);
    $Data = $Result->data;
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($Data); echo "</pre>";

    $CommentsSum = 0;
    $LikesSum = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($Data); $i++){
        $CommentsSum += $Data[$i]->comments->count;
        $LikesSum += $Data[$i]->likes->count;
    }
    //echo ' Comments '.$CommentsSum;
    //echo ' Likes '.$LikesSum;
    echo "<br />";

    if(isset($Result->pagination->next_url) && !empty($Result->pagination->next_url)){
        $next = $Result->pagination->next_url;
        $this->AddCampaignDetails($next);
    }else{
        $NextUrl = "";
        die;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

After this loop, I have echo `$CommentsSum;` variable and get this output

```
183
306
320
42
```

Now I want above number sum `851`.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you echo within loop?

Comment: Maybe after the end of the loop you could add $CommentsSum and $LikesSum together

Comment: Are you doing this inside another loop?

Comment: please post your full code. also, summing up a few number seems to be quite trivial...

Comment: @Joshua I have update question with full code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$Data[$i]->comments->count` must be a number, and it's seem that is a string, so it's merging string instead of doing math.

And If you really have a new line between each number (like you said in echo) maybe `$Data[$i]->comments->count` is equal to `"183\n"`

use for example :

```
$CommentsSum += intval($Data[$i]->comments->count)
```